# Bosonic Green's function at $i\omega_n=0$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions

A particle's Green's function $G(\omega)$ is analytic everywhere in the complex plane except along the real axis.

Does it mean that a bosonic $G(\omega)$ is possibly nonanalytic at the bosonic Matsubara frequency $i\omega_n=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. An explicit example: $G(\omega,k)=1/(\omega^2-c^2k^2)$, the Green's function of a phonon, is nonanalytic at the frequency $\omega=0$ or $\mathrm{i}\omega=0$ at the momentum point $k=0$.

Comment: would it be accurate to say that *any* system without mass-gap has a singularity at $\omega=0$?

Comment: @Everett, does this nonanalyticity have any implication? I believe analyticity is guaranteed at all other Matsubara points, both bosonic and fermionic.

Comment: This non-analyticity simply means that the boson is gapless.